# Update Label of a Custom Subclass of UITableViewCell after navigation return?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to update the score of one of the labels on my custom cell after returning from a push navigation.

In my parent `UITableViewController` I have the code:

In **ViewDidLoad**

```
//These are mutable strings
self.disciplineScoreString1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
self.disciplineScoreString2 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
self.disciplineScoreString3 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];

self.disciplineScoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.disciplineScoreArray addObject:self.disciplineScoreString1];
[self.disciplineScoreArray addObject:self.disciplineScoreString2];
[self.disciplineScoreArray addObject:self.disciplineScoreString3];
```

So far so good.

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
//this is the custom subclass of UITableViewCell
DayTableViewCell *cell = (DayTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//this is the custom label
cell.disciplineScoreLabel.text = [self.disciplineScoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

Still so far so good. Right now the label in each of the 3 cells is blank.

I now segue to a `UIViewController` from the first cell and I return from the `child UIViewController` successfully setting the string value of `self.disciplineScoreString1` to `@"10"`which I NSLog'ged in the `parent UITableViewController`.

How do I update the label for the first cell now? I have tried `reload data` in `ViewWillAppear` but its not working.

Thankyou

**EDIT**

This is the code in the `Child ViewController`

In **viewWillDisappear:**

```
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[self calculateDisciplineScore];

NSInteger currentVCIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.topViewController];

DisciplineTableViewController *parent = (DisciplineTableViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentVCIndex];

parent.disciplineScoreString1 = self.disciplineScoreText;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the values

Comment: It looks like @merlevede's answer is correct. `viewWillDisappear:` is probably not the best place to put this logic. This will commonly be done with a delegate or some kind of completion handler. Doing it the way you have makes your code very rigid

Comment: @Paul.s can you please show me an alternative and ill accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be changing the string, instead of modifying it... consider this example

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableString *disciplineScoreString1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"original string"];
[array addObject:disciplineScoreString1];

[disciplineScoreString1 appendString:@" hello"]; // OK.. you're modifying the original string
NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);

disciplineScoreString1 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"new string"]; // WRONG!!
NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The ouput is:

```
2014-02-15 06:36:46.693 Hello[19493:903] original string hello
2014-02-15 06:36:46.694 Hello[19493:903] original string hello
```

The second example is wrong because you're creating a new string, and the object in the array is still pointing to the old original string.

EDIT:

```
// try this
[parent.disciplineScoreString1 replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, parent.disciplineScoreString1.length) withString:self.disciplineScoreText];
// instead of 
parent.disciplineScoreString1 = self.disciplineScoreText;
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added where I am trying to change the string. I am kind of getting what you are saying, but can you please help me a little further with the edit i just made. :)

Comment: thanks works a treat. I should also add to other readers, you should call [self.tableView reload data] in viewWillAppear on the parent tvc

Comment: just for further clarification. If disciplineScoreString1 was a NSString instead, my situation would not work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is quite rigid and not very standard. You would normally set up some kind of delegate to pass data from a child to a parent. It is very rarely correct that a child should know how to reach into the parent's innards and change it's data.

I would personally start with something like this

```
@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onCompletion)(ChildViewController *viewController, NSString *disciplineText);

@end
```

Now I'm assuming you are dismissing by just calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` from within the child? This is a little odd as it means that the childViewController can now only ever be presented in a navigationController, this makes it less reusable.

What I would do is at the point where you normally call `popViewControllerAnimated:` I would call the completion instead

```
if (self.onCompletion) {
  self.onCompletion(self, self.disciplineText);
}
```

Now the object who provides the `onCompletion` can decide how this controller get's removed and it's told about the data that we finished with, which enabled the controller to do what it wants with it.

In your case the parent controller would provide the completion as it knows how the child is presented so it will know how to dismiss it. It also know that it may want to do something with the data the child finished with

```
// Where you present the child

childViewController.disciplineText = self.self.disciplineScoreArray[index];

__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
childViewController.onCompletion = ^(ChildViewController *viewController, NSString *disciplineText){
  weakSelf.disciplineScoreArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:disciplineText];
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [weakSelf.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] ] 
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
};
```